# Expand C# string with control characters

Tags: c#, string, substring, stringbuilder

I need to expand the Control Characters (non-Printable) in a Bar Code Scan.

This is what I've got. At the moment I am hung up on how to get the integer index from the substring on my input string.

```
    // A method for expanding ASCII Control Character into Human Readable format
    string ExpandCtrlString(string inStr)
    {
        // String Builder Capacity may need to be lengthened...
        StringBuilder outStr = new StringBuilder(128);
        // 0 Based Array representing the expansion of ASCII Control Characters
        string[] CtrlChars = new string[]
        {
            "<nul>",
            "<soh>",
            "<stx>",
            "<etx>",
            "<eot>",
            "<enq>",
            "<ack>",
            "<bel>",
            "<bs>",
            "<tab>",
            "<lf>",
            "<vt>",
            "<ff>",
            "<cr>",
            "<so>",
            "<si>",
            "<dle>",
            "<dc1>",
            "<dc2>",
            "<dc3>",
            "<dc4>",
            "<nak>",
            "<syn>",
            "<etb>",
            "<can>",
            "<em>",
            "<sub>",
            "<esc>",
            "<fs>",
            "<gs>",
            "<rs>",
            "<us>"
        };

        for (int n = 0; n < inStr.Length; n++)
        {
            if (Char.IsControl(inStr, n))
            {
                //char q = inStr.Substring(n, 1);
                int x = (int)inStr[n] ();
                outStr.Append(CtrlChars[x]);
            }
            else
            {
                outStr.Append(inStr.Substring(n, 1));
            }
        }
        return outStr.ToString();
    }
```

Edited:
The thought came as I was musing...

I double cast the substring and it worked...

That is I casted the cast... :)

```
    for (int n = 0; n < inStr.Length; n++)
    {
        if (Char.IsControl(inStr, n))
        {
            int x = (int)(char)inStr[n];
            outStr.Append(CtrlChars[x]);
        }
        else
        {
            outStr.Append(inStr.Substring(n, 1));
        }
    }
    return outStr.ToString();
```

And, it works in CF NET 2.0 in Windows Mobile 5

I had thought about using foreach, but, that presented other problems for an old VB6 guy. :)

Comment: At the first glace the code looks good. What's not working? Is `inStr[n] ()` a typo? The braces shouldn't be there.

Comment: @SamLeach .. while I agree with your editing of the textual components, I don't think its in the best interests of the question to edit the code of the question itself.  IMHO that detracts from our understanding of where the OP is coming from, invalidates statements previously made by other commentators, plus the code is still flawed.  If you want to point out where the OP is wrong then an answer is bet place for it.

Answer (score 0):

A char can be used like a number. Here's a simpler loop:

```
foreach (char c in inStr)
{
    // Check to see if c (as a number here) is less than the CtrlChars array size
    // If it is, then print the CtrlChars text
    if (c < CtrlChars.Length)   
    {
        outStr.Append(CtrlChars[c]);
    }
    else
    {
        outStr.Append(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had thought about using foreach... But, as I don't understand exactly what's going on: if (c < CtrlChars.Length), yet, probably best to leave the code as it ended up. At least for now.

Comment: Ok. Added comment to explain. Basically it says if c is less than 33, print the CtrlChars text.

Comment: Ah... I missed that! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can see where you are are coming from in your approach, but I can see some flaws in what you are trying to do as well.

First of all .. I'm doing this without testing .. so buyer beware!

Secondly, from Microsoft's [Char.IsControl Method (String, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9s05w2k9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `The Unicode standard assigns code points from \U0000 to \U001F, \U007F, and from \U0080 to \U009F to control characters.`   Your array doesn't cover all of these ranges, so potentially (depending on the source of your string) your code will actually blow up as you would be supplying an index that is outside the range of the array.  This could be fixed by using a dictionary to map from a number to string, rather than the array.

```
dictionary<int, string> mapping = new dictionary<int, string>() {
  { 0, "<nul>" },
  { 1, "<soh>"  },

  .. etc filled with every possible control char
}
```

NOTE that this dictionary really should be defined/constructed in the **class** that holds your `ExpandCtrlString` method, and not in the method itself.

```
class expand
{
   private dictionary<int, string> mapping …

   public string ExpandCtrlString(string inStr)
   {
     ...
    }

}
```

And to get your char you can simply do:

```
for (int n = 0; n < inStr.Length; n++)   
{
    char ch = instr[n];
    ...
}
```

Or if you want to be more modern about it you can directly get the character from the string:

```
foreach(var ch in instr)
{
    ...
}
```

Then check if the char is a control char, and if so is it in the dictionary

```
if (Char.IsControl(ch))
{
    // The value is not needed until you know its a control char
    int val = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(ch);

    if (mapping.ContainsKey(val))
    {
        // You know what the control char is, so output its name
        outStr.Append(mapping[val]);
    }
    else
    {
       // You might have missed a control char in your dictionary of names
       // So by default output its hex value instead
       outStr.AppendFormat("<{0}>", val.ToString("X"));  
    }
}
else
{
    // Char is not a control char
    outStr.Append(ch);
}
```

Then finally return your outStr as you already do.

Comment: While there is a second level of Unicode Control Characters from 80 to 9F, the bar code scanner does not, AFAIK, output anything above ASCII 127. But, I will be aware of the potential. Also, by using a Switch statement anything not covered specifically in the switch cases will fall out to the Default statement. So, for now I should be alright. Thanks for answering.